# My groovy script in Jmeter executes without error but it fails to Insert document in Mongo DB, what could be wrong?

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

I have written following script in Jmeter for insertion of a Document in MongoDB. My script executes successfully however it doesn't do the required task i-e does not insert record in database. What am I missing? can anyone plz help

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;
try {
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
.build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));
vars.putObject("collection", collection);
return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");




//String json = ('{"EmployeeOID":12345,"EmployeeName":"Test Automation through Jmeter","Employee_Type_OID":4,"Rank":0,"Rating":0,"Score":0,"Supervisor_OID":56789,"TRGEmpID":"012345T"}');
//DBObject insertEmployee = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);


BasicDBObject insertEmployee = new BasicDBObject();
    insertEmployee.put("EmployeeOID",12345);
    insertEmployee.put("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter");
    insertEmployee.put("Employee_Type_OID",4);
        insertEmployee.put("Rank",0);
            insertEmployee.put("Rating",0);
                insertEmployee.put("Score",0);
                    insertEmployee.put("Supervisor_OID",56789);
                        insertEmployee.put("CompanyID","012345T");


    collection.insert(insertEmployee);

    DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
    while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());

    }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have [`return` keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_return.asp) in your script, at this stage execution ends. Lines which are below the `return` keyword will never be executed therefore you fail to see the inserted object because code doesn't run.

[image]

Remove this line:

```
return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
```

and your script should start working as expected (or at least start failing)

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

Comment: I commented the said line but no luck :( still script is passing yet no insertions in DB

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess what's wrong without seeing the details so here are 2 hints: 1. Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect "Sampler Result" tab for any errors. 2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for any suspicious entries (you may want to enable debug logging for  `com.mongodb` package

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter is old